# JSTL syntax for request.getScheme() method?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I would like to convert some piece of code in JSTL. To be specific I implemented

```
<c:if test='${request.scheme == "http"}'>
</c:if>
```

as a replacement of

```
if ("http").equals(request.getScheme()) {
    //do something
}
```

but it looks like JSTL syntax is not correct and the condition never matches. I do not get any error though.

Is my syntax incorrect?

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${request}` implicit EL object doesn't exist in plain JSP. It only exists in several MVC frameworks which also utilize EL, such as JSF. You could easily have figured out it yourself by simply printing the `${request}` directly and noticing it actually prints nothing.

```
The request implicit EL object is: ${request}
```

In plain JSP, the `ServletRequest` is only available by [`PageContext#getRequest()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#getRequest--) and the [`PageContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html) is in turn available as implicit EL object `${pageContext}`.

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.scheme eq 'http'}">
    ...
</c:if>
```

Note that singlequotes are valid to represent a `String` in EL.

#### See also

- [Or EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, in case you actually intend to distinguish a secure (SSL) request from an unsecure one, you'd better check [`ServletRequest#isSecure()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#isSecure--) instead.

```
<c:if test="${not pageContext.request.secure}">
    ...
</c:if>
```